# long list selector jump list scren windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm using a grouped long list selector in a windows phone application. It has the normal behaviour, whenever I tap on one header, the jump list screen is open. However, I want to trigger this when I'm navigating on the page without any interaction from the user. Is there a possibility to display the jump list when navigating to a page without any user interaction? Thank you

```
<phone:LongListSelector
                Height="570"
                Margin="0,-10,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                LayoutMode="List"
                x:Name="SizeLLs"
                SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged_1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentProduct.product_variations, Source={StaticResource LocalVariablesResources}}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="12,10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Assets/emptyCircle.png" ></Image>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Assets/check50pxRadioBT.png" Visibility="{Binding isSelected, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" ></Image>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Normal" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="15,10,10,10" Foreground="#878780" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding title}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="15,10,5,10" Foreground="#878780" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding price}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="0,10,15,10" Foreground="#878780" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentConfiguration.currency_symbol, Source={StaticResource LocalVariablesResources}}"></TextBlock>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: Would DisplayGroupView() work?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately for you, LongListselector doesn't have this functionality publically exposed.

You could take [the WP7 source code of the control](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/LongListSelector/), and add the functionality you need (i.e. make `OpenPopup` method public).